# Primefaces p:commandLink not working in above IE8?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-8

My tag p:commandLink is not working above IE8 (working fine in IE8).

My xhtml is something like this :

```
        <h:head>
        <script type="text/javascript">​
                function show_confirm() {
                //<![CDATA[
                    var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
                        if (conf == true) {
                            document.getElementById("scheduleManagerForm:delrow").click();
                        }
                    //]]>
                }

                function run_the_Job_Confirmation() {
                    //<![CDATA[
                        var conf = confirm('Are you sure you want to run it now?');
                            if (conf == true) {
                                document.getElementById("scheduleManagerForm:runrow").click();
                            }
                        //]]>
                    }

            </script>
        </h:head>

    <body>
    <h:form>    
    <p:dataTable id="jobSchedules" var="js" value="#{SJBean.listOfJobScheduleDTO}" 
                               selectionMode="single" selection="#{SJBean.selectedJobSchedule}"
                              rowSelectListener="#{SJBean.onRowSelect}"
                              rowEditListener="#{SJBean.rowEdit}" onRowEditUpdate="jobSchedules msgs">

        <p:column style="width:150px;" headerText="Edit">
                <p:rowEditor update="scheduleManagerForm:jobListPanel" oncomplete="location.reload()"/>
                <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" onclick="show_confirm();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{SJBean.selectedJobSchedule}" value="#{js}" />
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-play" onclick="run_the_Job_Confirmation();"></p:commandLink>
        </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
<h:commandButton id="delrow" value="ok" style="visibility:hidden;">
                                        <f:ajax listener="#{SJBean.deleteRow}" render="msgs jobSchedules"></f:ajax>
                                    </h:commandButton>
                                    <h:commandButton id="runrow" value="ok" style="visibility:hidden;">
                                        <f:ajax listener="#{SJBean.runTheJob}" render="msgs"></f:ajax>
                                    </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    </body>
```

When user clicks delete icon and show_confirm() is not triggered  (checked by putting a debug point in firefox).

The same code get executed in IE 8 flawlessly.
I am using Primefaces 2.2 as it what the application is made of .

Comment: At least you need <h:body> instead of <body>

Answer (score 0):

There was an invisible character in my javascript. It was invisible in my text editor (the one in Eclipse) but when I open in notepad I was able to see it.
That was prohibiting it from executing the javascript. Removed it , its all working fine now.